# How to insert an input with different values in to the mysql database using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, input, insert

I have got a form with some inputs like:

```
<form action="http://site.com" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="image_Title" value="Image" />
<input type="text" name="image_Basename" value="0000001" />
<input type="text" name="image_basename" value="0000002" />
<input type="text" name="image_basename" value="0000003" />
</form>
```

How can I insert each `image_Id` with the same `image_Title` to one row using Codeigniter?! I used foreach, but I couldn't make it work?!

for example:

```
table-row-name:image_Title              table-row-name:image_Basename
       'Image'                                '00000001'
       'Image'                                '00000002'
       'Image'                                '00000003'
       'Image2'                               '00000258'
       'Image2'                               '00000102'
```

How can I do that ?!

This is my php code ( of cource in Codeigniter):

```
foreach($_POST['image_Basename'] as $image_Basename) 
{
    $image_Id = $this->gallery_model->add(array('image_Title' => $_POST['image_Title'], 'image_Basename' => $image_Basename)); 
}
```

My Model:

```
function add($options = array())
{

    $options = array(

    'image_Title' => $_Post['image_Title'],

    'image_Basename' => $image_Basename

    );

    $this->db->insert('mg_gallery', $options);

    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: How are you inserting? What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP. I will test your solution and will inform you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP, add `[]` to the `input` names, and you'll receive an array of values.

In the HTML

```
<input type="text" name="image_Id[]" value="0000003" />
```

With [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (no error checking, no connecting):

```
foreach ($_POST['image_Id'] as $id) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bin_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: then, how can I insert them?!

Comment: Show some code of what you have tried. Basically, you loop over the array you receive from `$_POST` and insert the values.

Comment: how should I insert `name="name[]"` in to the database in general?!

Comment: @Afshin I updated my answer. I don't know CodeIgniter, so I cannot help you with that. This is how it works in plain PHP.